# Protractor: Can you select a binding without wrapping it in an element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

According to the docs, there is a method called by.exactBinding() that selects an element very accurately [ProtractorBy.prototype.exactBinding](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-protractorby-prototype-exactbinding)

So that in the case of

```
<span>{{ person.name }}</span>
```

You can successfully test like:

```
expect(element(by.exactBinding('person.name')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
expect(element(by.exactBinding('person')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

However, but what about a case where you have bindings like this:

```
<div>Showing {{foo.foo}} of {{foo.bar}}</div>
```

In that case, even if you were to use the exactBinding() selector and the models were 1 and 2:

```
expect(element(by.exactBinding('foo.foo')).getText()).toEqual('1');
```

that test would always fail because the getText() value of this selector:

```
element(by.exactBinding('foo.foo'))
```

will actually be "Showing 1 of 2", not just "1" like I would like.

A quick and dirty way to get around this would be to wrap each binding in an element like this:

```
<div>Showing <span>{{foo.foo}}</span> of <span>{{foo.bar}}</span></div>
```

Which works fine, but this is extra useless markup! I can't find any other way to select though. Turning a binding into an element with ng-bind also works, but is just as dirty of a fix. So the question would be, is there a way to just select just the binding? Without adding useless markup to my page? This would be really useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't, the idea for this is to be used as locator for finding the element, so if it's not an element you won't be able, you can get around using .toMatch() so it will try finding at least one result, otherwise you must say that will be equal to all the text expected "Showing 1 of 2".